# ajax response function can't redirect the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On button click ajax function for redirecting the page.

```
   $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "logindata.php",
                   data: {request:uname,request1:upass},
                   success: function(){ 
},
complete: function(response)
    {
if((response.responseText)=="Done"){
window.location.assign('enter.php');
}

  $("#status").html("<font color='red'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");

 }
```

my php code `logindata.php`

echo "Done";

I AM getting output `Done` but can't redirect the page

Comment: tried this ? `window.location.href = "enter.php";`

Comment: $(location).attr('href',your_url);

Comment: Why use AJAX and then redirect to another page? That makes the use of AJAX pointless.

Comment: so how could i move my client who had login successfully to dashboard.

Comment: @user3829658 you can do that in `PHP` after user inputs correct credentials [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: but this will work in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `window.location.href = "enter.php"` in place of `window.location.assign('enter.php');` ?

Comment: yes it gives same error . but i think the problem is in `==`

Comment: try using your function(response) in success: in place of complete: or  use console.log() for debug. == is fine, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in window.location.assign(**'enter.php'**).
You have to show the path correctly.